# Currently have a huge csv file, and want to sort the values by date?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a csv file with a lot of tables, and dates ranging from 1/1/2019 - 31/1/2019 ... of different years
I need to sum all the columns X for all the years, and have a graph, of how Each month changes per different years.
and how in one specific year different months show the X values differently.

using pandas. and matplotlib.

```
muestradatos[muestradatos.DateMonth == 1]


This is what the query in pandas shows
1/1/2019 455
1/2/2019 555
1/3/2019 15
1/4/2019 655
.
.
1/1/2017 644
```

I need it to show

```
Year 2019

JANUARY (the whole month) 50

FEBRUARY                  30

Year 2012
...
...
...
```

Comment: show you current code and display few lines of your data. You can add a desired output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pd.to_datetime()  to turn it into a date.
df.sort_values(by='Date')